# Clojuratica setup

Tags: clojure, wolfram-mathematica, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to get Clojuratica set up (MMa v 9 free trial) (on a Mac running Mavericks)

I am following the instructions in "Clojure Data Analysis Cookbook" but have also followed the instructions:

```
http://drcabana.org/2012/10/23/installation-and-configuration-of-clojuratica/
http://clojuratica.weebly.com/tutorial.html
```

I get the error message:

```
user=> (MathLinkFactory/createKernelLink path)
Fatal error: cannot find the required native library named JLinkNativeLibrary.

UnsatisfiedLinkError com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;  [Ljava/lang/String;)J  com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString (NativeLink.java:-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JVM cannot find the needed native library file. This is not necessarily the class path but `java.library.path` (I think). I did get it work once with the ZeroMQ client, I probably followed [these instructions](http://augustl.com/blog/2013/using_zeromq_from_clojure/), especially the extra jvm-argument in step 3 "Set up Leiningen".

Comment: This is correct. The string to add to project.clj is:

`:jvm-opts ["-Djava.library.path=/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/SystemFiles/Libraries/MacOSX-x86-64"]`  for 64 bit Mac; the exact directory varies by platform.